# Firebase Firestore nested collection in Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement the nested query with Firestore in Cloud Functions but stumbled upon issues with reading values in a `for` loop. Are there ways to adjust the following code so I could do some operations after reading all records from a collection?

```js
const firestore = admin.firestore();
        const today = new Date();

        const snap = await firestore
            .collection('places')
            .where('endDate', '<', today)
            .get()

        const userIds = [...new Set(snap.docs.map((doc: any) => doc.data().owner))];

        const updatePromises = snap.docs.map((d: any) => {
            return d.ref.update({
                isPaid: false,
                isActive: false
            })
        })

        await Promise.all(updatePromises);

        const userCol = firestore.collection('users');
        const userDocs = await Promise.all(userIds.map(uid => userCol.doc(uid).get()));
        const userData = userDocs.reduce((acc, doc) => ({
            ...acc,
            [doc.id]: doc.data()
        }), {})

        snap.docs.forEach((l: any) => {
            const ownerData = userData[l.owner];
            const { email, displayName } = ownerData;

            console.log(email, displayName);

            const message = {
                // Some values
            }

            return sendGrid.send(message);
        })

        return null;
```

```js
{ owner: '<firebaseUid'>, address: 'Royal Cr. Road 234' }
```

```js
{ email: 'asdfa@afsdf.com' }
```

```json
<firebase_uid>: {
  displayName: '',
  email: '',
  phoneNumber: ''
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "some operations after reading all records"?

Answer (score 0):

The `userIds.push(owner);` will keep adding duplicate values in that array and if a single user is owner of multiple locations, you'll end up querying same data multiple times. If you are trying to read owner's data along with a location, then try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
const firestore = admin.firestore();
const today = new Date();

const snap = await firestore
  .collection('locations')
  .where('isActive', '==', true)
  .get()

const userIds = [...new Set(snap.docs.map(doc => doc.data().owner))];

const updatePromises = snap.docs.map((d) => {
  return d.ref.update({
    isPaid: false,
    isActive: false
  })
})

// update documents 
await Promise.all(updatePromises);

const userCol = firestore.collection("users")
const userDocs = await Promise.all(userIds.map(uid => userCol.doc(uid).get()))
const userData = userDocs.reduce((acc, doc) => ({
  ...acc,
  [doc.id]: doc.data()
}), {})

// To get data of a location's owner
// console.log(userData[ownerId])

snap.docs.forEach((l) => {
  const ownerData = userData[l.owner]
  // run more logic for each user
})

return null;
```

Comment: So if the user record has the `email` field, this shall now be available with `const { email } = userData;`, correct?

Comment: @Aleksandrs `userData` is an object where keys are user IDs and value is the data of that user. So you can use `const {email} = userData[userId]` where `userId` some owner ID from the `locations` documents.

Comment: do i have to make another loop to access it?

Comment: @Aleksandrs can you explain what are you trying to do? I assume you have a location's owner's ID and want to get that user's email or data? How are you rendering all the locations at first place? You must be mapping the data somewhere? I updated the answer if that's what you are looking for?

Comment: i am trying to hide unpaid locations and then notify users by email with SendGrid. the location has owner, which references the userID in users table. the users table in turn stores records with emails, so i want function to find the collection, get users through the reference, and then send out emails

Comment: @Aleksandrs there's no context about that in your question. We don't know how you figure out if a location is unpaid or no. If that's a field you can just use a query `where("unpaid", "==", false)` so something similar. For your original question, you can iterate over the array and call your sendgrid service. Updated answer

Comment: something is wrong with the code. do you refer to querySnapshot as snap?

Comment: the values in `locations` also don't get updated

Comment: so can i now access the email with `const ownerData = userData[l.owner]            const { email } = ownerData;`?

Comment: @Aleksandrs yes. that's correct. Also that `querySnapshot` is supposed to be `snap` yes.

Comment: Cannot destructure property 'email' of 'ownerData' as it is undefined.

Comment: could you please help in adjusting this?

Comment: @Aleksandrs that means the value is undefined. My best guess is there is no document with ID as owner's UID. Also please update the code that you are running now in your question if that's not the case.

Comment: Updated the code. You are right. owner does not have the ID field, it should be the document ID

Comment: The document ID must be user's Firebase Auth UID in users collection. @Aleksandrs

Comment: yes, but it still undefined, or do you mean i have to change something?

Comment: @Aleksandrs the code seems fine. Do you mind `console.log(userData)` and share a screenshot of that? Also a screenshot of your users collection document might help to verify that the document actually exists

Comment: @Aleksandrs doesn't include a screenshot from Firestore. Your data is missing but the code seems to be correct then.

Comment: can i point to the document id so i don't have to include in a users record?